# How to run a stack build in a Docker container?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'd like to set up a containerized build of a Haskell stack project for work. I know that `stack --docker build` exists, but I'd like to do this just with docker, so my colleagues are not required to first install `stack`.

I currently have a Dockerfile that looks like:

```
FROM fpco/stack-build:lts-8.9
RUN mkdir -p /stack && stack --stack-root /stack setup --resolver lts-8.9
COPY build.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/build.sh"]
```

And am running `stack` as:

```
stack build --stack-root=/stack --resolver=lts-8.9
```

However, this has the following problems:

- it rebuilds all of the dependencies every time
- it requires `--allow-different-users`, as it seems to be re-using my local `.stack-work`, which seems less than ideal

I also haven't figured out whether it will break native stack builds, or things like intero.

Comment: If you want to cache things in docker, you'll need a separate line. https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/694 comes somewhat close.

Answer (score 0):

I typically put a `volumes` section in an accompanying `docker-compose.yml` file that will mount the `.stack-work` directory into the container. Then in the script that is referenced in the `ENTRYPOINT` of the `Dockerfile`, use `stack install` instead of `stack build`.

My `docker-compose.yml` file might look something like this, where the `backend` folder contains my local `.stack-work` directory:

```
version: "2"
services:
  backend:
    build: ./docker-containers/backend
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true   
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/home/dev/backend
      - ./.local:/root/.local
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is as follows.

Note that the docker image for build does not have stack setup.

```
FROM fpco/stack-build:lts-9.14
ADD ./build.sh /bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["build.sh"]
```

Run stack setup in `build.sh` like this:

```
stack setup --resolver=lts-9.14 --allow-different-user
stack build --allow-different-user
```

Mount the project dir and stack_root from host at runtime.

```
docker run -w /workspace -v ~/myproject:/workspace -v ~/.stack:/root/.stack
```

Comment: Does this mean that the host operating system's `~/.stack` folder is used by the container operating system? What if they are different operating systems? Then I think it won't be able to re-use your previously built dependancies. Or, if the files made in the container overwrite what is in your host's `~/.stack` then you will have problems.